# Google Sheets: How to combine Filter, Query, and MINIFS

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Edit: [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b9dWvEzYYVzxWK6ZzJBPRqFvKcJVQujYug_98hAVoFA/edit?usp=sharing) is a spreadsheet with dummy data.

I'm working with accounting data and trying to come up with a table like this to figure out what I have to pay in the upcoming payment:

| Price | Quantity | Total Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.50 | 600 | 300.00 |
| 0.10 | 1000 | 100.00 |

My data is a table of prices and quantities and arbitrary dates of payment. Cell addresses in parentheses

| Price (N2) | Quantity (O2) | (P2) 1/1/2021 | (Q2) 2/9/2021 | (R2) 5/2/2021 | (S2) 10/5/2021 | (T2) 11/4/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.25 | 100 |  |  |  |  | 25.00 |
| 0.70 | 2 | 1.40 |  |  |  |  |
| 0.50 | 500 |  |  |  | 250.00 |  |
| 0.10 | 1000 |  |  |  | 100.00 |  |
| 0.50 | 100 |  |  |  | 50.00 |  |

The values in the date columns always equal the price multiplied by quantity, and each row only has an entry in a single date column.
I want to proactively calculate how much needs to be paid in the soonest date of payment that is also in the future. So for example, since today is September 10th, it would be the amounts for October 5th, 2021.

**What I've tried so far:**

To do the final calculation use a query like this:

```
=QUERY(table_from_filter,"select Price , sum(Quantity), Price*SUM(Quantity) group by Price ")
```

To get the values for the query above I use a filter statement like this to filter out prices and quantities that are not in the column for 10/5/2021 (column S):

```
=filter(P2:T2,S2:S <> " ")
```

I've also been able to get the value 10/5/2021 using this formula

```
=MINIFS(O2:T2,O2:T2,">"&TODAY())
```

How can I combine / adjust all three formulas to get the desired result table for payments for only the soonest upcoming date without hardcoding the column letter?

Comment: it could be easier for everybody to share a spreadsheet

Comment: Added it on to the beginning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curly brackets `{A:E}` then use `Col1,Col2,Colx` and replace x by the result in L5, so try

```
=query({A:E},"select Col1,Col2,Col"&L5&" where Col"&L5&"<>' ' ")
```

with in L5

```
=match(MINIFS(C2:E2,C2:E2,">"&TODAY()),A2:E2,0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to group the results by price like in my example in cell F4? I tried adding GROUP BY Col2 but it didn't work

Comment: `=query({A4:E},"select Col2,sum(Col1),Col2*sum(Col1) where Col"&L5&"<>' ' group by Col2 offset 1")`

Answer (score 0):

#### Proposed solution

```
=QUERY(
    {
        A2:B14,
        FILTER(
            C2:E14,
            C2:E2 = MIN(
                ARRAYFORMULA(
                    FILTER(C2:E2, C2:E2 - TODAY() > 0) - TODAY()
                )
            ) + TODAY()
        )
    },
"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col3 is not null")
```

Play around with it here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n3ZOyKiH9p2nref6TbsVKkKQsxBzoxasNlflpa4Hq8s/edit?usp=sharing

I copied it into a new document because you had inserted spaces into some blank cells which were preventing `is not null` from working, and deleting these spaces seemed to mess with your formulae.

I changed your "date finder" to:

```
MIN(
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        FILTER(C2:E2, C2:E2 - TODAY() > 0) - TODAY()
    )
) + TODAY()
```

Which first uses `ARRAYFORMULA` to subtract `TODAY()` from the dates, and if there are any negative values then `FILTER` them. Then take the `MIN` and add `TODAY()` again to get the date.

With this I created an array to use `QUERY` on:

```
{
    A2:B14,
    FILTER(
        C2:E14,
        C2:E2 = MIN(
            ARRAYFORMULA(
                FILTER(C2:E2, C2:E2 - TODAY() > 0) - TODAY()
            )
        ) + TODAY()
    )
}
```

From there, I used the `QUERY` to just filter out the blank ones.